# How to make a function return two different type of variable?

Tags: c#

So I was trying to make a power method in c# but I came across a problem when I try to do a negative exponent because the result can't be an integer therefore it can't be returned. I tried converting the result to be an integer but that is not accurate. Is there any solution where I can return different data types? I want to use only a single method if that's possible.

```
    static int Power(int num1, int num2)    
    {
        if (num2 == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (num2 == 1)
        {
            return num1;
        }
        else if (num2 > 1)
        {
            int sum = num1;
            for (int i = 1; i != num2; i++)
            {
                sum = sum * num1;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        else
        {
            int sum;
            num2 = num2 * 1;
            sum = Power(num1, num2);
            float sumFloat = (float)sum; 
            sumFloat = 1 / sumFloat;
            return sumFloat;    //Can't return this.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert `sumFloat` to int. just like this `return Convert.ToInt32(sumFloat)`

Comment: You could make the return value a `float` for all cases or have a look into [`OneOf`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf/), return a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), a custom result type (class or record or struct) ...

Comment: You can do it by using tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Return only float value, (and in your code has some errors if num2 is negative number your method runs infinitely)

```
        static float Power(int num1, int num2)
        {
            if (num2 == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (num2 == 1)
            {
                return num1;
            }
            else if (num2 > 1)
            {
                int sum = num1;
                for (int i = 1; i != num2; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum * num1;
                }
                return sum;
            }
            else
            {
                float sum;
                num2 = num2 * (-1);
                sum = Power(num1, num2);
                float sumFloat = (float)sum;
                sumFloat = 1 / sumFloat;
                return sumFloat;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. Each method with a given signature has exactly one return type.

Long answer: You have a few options to work around this, each with their own pros and cons.

Option 1: You could make your return type more general. If `int` is not general enough, you might need to return a `float` or `double` instead. However be careful with this, as you will get floating point errors, e.g. you might get something like 3^2 = 8.999999999999999999999 etc.

Option 2: You can accept `uint` instead of `int` for the non-negative case, and `int` for the negative case. The non-negative case can return an `int` and the negative case can return a `float`. I think this is quite messy, and I don't suggest you use this option.

Option 3: Your return type could be something like `(int? IntAnswer, float? RealAnswer)` and you can set exactly one of them. e.g. `return (sum, null)` or `return (null, sumFloat)`. The advantage of doing it this way is you can have `int` exactness for the non-negative case and you can still handle the real answers for the negative case.

There are certainly many ways to skin a cat. At the end of the day, the operation you are doing (power) is a mathematical concept that goes even beyond integers and real numbers. For example powers can accept/return complex numbers.

Unless you have a very specific need for integer precision (avoiding floating point errors), I would go with Option 1.

I guess the bigger question is: why are you implementing a Power method in the first place? It is [already part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-5.0) of the `Math` namespace.

Comment: 3rd option did the job. Thanks ^_^

Comment: I think that the 3rd option is the worst. Now you have to do a bunch of `if` statements to do something meaningful with the results. Option 2 is by far the most suitable option. Make the compiler do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The other option you have here is to use the `BigInteger` and `BigRational` libraries. Both of these types are structs that can represent arbitrarily large integers and rational values. You literally have to run out of memory to have an overflow value.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
static BigRational Power(BigInteger num1, BigInteger num2)
{
    if (num2 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (num2 == 1)
    {
        return num1;
    }
    else if (num2 > 0)
    {
        BigInteger sum = num1;
        for (BigInteger i = 1; i != num2; i++)
        {
            sum = sum * num1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 / Power(num1, -num2);
    }
}
```

You run it like normal:

```
BigRational r = Power(10, 4);
Console.WriteLine(r.Numerator);   // 10000
Console.WriteLine(r.Denominator); // 1
```

if the `Denominator` is `1` you have a whole number which in the `Numerator`.

If you work with negative powers then you have this situation:

```
BigRational r = Power(10, -4);
Console.WriteLine(r.Numerator);   // 1
Console.WriteLine(r.Denominator); // 10000
```

if the `Numerator` is `1` you have a fractional number which in the `Denominator` is the base.

It's then super easy to do this:

```
double result = (double)r;
```

You could then easily go define the other overloads that you might need:

```
static BigRational Power(BigRational num1, BigInteger num2)
static BigRational Power(BigInteger num1, BigRational num2)
static BigRational Power(BigRational num1, BigRational num2)
```

It becomes quite powerful and you never need to get any rounding issues because you're never working with doubles or floats.

Just NuGet `BigRationalLibrary` to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about returning a value that can be one of several types, this is known as a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), variant or discriminated union. In implementations it is sometimes called an 'Either', that uses generics to express the possible types a value might take. See [c# Monads library for an example](https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad/blob/main/CSharpMonad/src/EitherStrict.cs).

I would recommend using such patterns sparingly since it will make calling the method more cumbersome. In your example it might be more appropriate to simply have two or more variants using different types.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can return **two type data** from one function or **more than two result**.

But **I Dont Sure** about it that method works because it was **static**

Like code below (Check Syntax):

```
static (int,float) Power(int num1, int num2)    
{
    if (num2 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (num2 == 1)
    {
        return num1;
    }
    else if (num2 > 1)
    {
        int sum = num1;
        for (int i = 1; i != num2; i++)
        {
            sum = sum * num1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        int sum;
        num2 = num2 * 1;
        sum = Power(num1, num2);
        float sumFloat = (float)sum; 
        sumFloat = 1 / sumFloat;
        return (sum,sumFloat); // Sum is  Int
    }
}
```

after that if you want get one of them You can select like this:

**Power.Item1** or **Power.Item2**

I Wish its Helps To you

Sorry for bad English